# Jquery Select with Checkbox and Highlight Single Table Row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net core mvc application.  In a view I have two tables.  Each table has a checkbox to select a row.  I want the user to be able to select a single row in each table and have the row highlighted.  Here is my jquery code:

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table1 input:checkbox").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor', $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color'));
                $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', 'yellowgreen');
            } else {
                $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor'));
            }
        });
        $("#table1 input:checkbox").change(function () {
            $("#table1 input:checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });

        $("#table2 input:checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor', $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color'));
                $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', 'yellowgreen');
            } else {
                $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor'));
            }
        });
        $("#table2 input:checkbox").change(function () {
            $("#table2 input:checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    });
```

Everything works great with the highlighting if I do not try to limit the single checkbox selection.  But adding that caused the rows to remain highlighted instead of toggling.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I will also add that I tried to do this under the .click function in the .checked condition, but same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just store the checkbox that was clicked, remove all the checked checkboxes and all the highlighting on the table, then just re-check the checkbox and add the highlighting.

here is a fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/6nx2yz0q/

```
$("#table1 input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $("#table1 input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        $("#table1 tr").removeClass('bg-info');
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('bg-info');
      });
```

Comment: Hello there! I'm trying to implement this code but I need to be able to select more than 1 row and for every row selected to be highlighted and also to be able to deselect any given row and it should return back to the normal color. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: @Sfmar $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table1 input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass('bg-info');
    } else {
      //$("#table1 tr").removeClass('bg-info');
      // $("#table1 input:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('bg-info');
    }
  });
});